# Does the "fury of the Time Lord" scene occur in the original Human Nature?

Tags: doctor-who, adaptation-comparison

The two-part TV episode *Human Nature*/*The Family of Blood* was originally a *Virgin New Adventures* book, also called *Human Nature*. The TV story ends with this brutal scene (taken from [a transcript](https://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/29-9.htm)):

> (The Family run, then their spaceship goes KaBOOM!)
>
>  BAINES [OC]: He never raised his voice. That was the worst thing. The fury of the Time Lord. And then we discovered why. Why this Doctor, who had fought with gods and demons, why he'd run away from us and hidden. He was being kind.
>
>  (Clark, wearing heavy chains, falls into a pit.)
>
>  BAINES [OC]: He wrapped my father in unbreakable chains, forged in the heart of a dwarf star. He tricked my mother into the event horizon of a collapsing galaxy to be imprisoned there forever.
>
>  (Jenny is sucked out of the Tardis in deep space.)
>
>  BAINES [OC]: He still visits my little sister once a year every year. I wonder if one day he might forgive her, but there she is. Can you see? He trapped her inside a mirror, every mirror. If ever you look at your reflection and see something move behind you, just for a second, that's her. That's always her. As for me, I was suspended in time. And the Doctor put me to work standing over the fields of England, as their protector.
>
>  (Baines has become a scarecrow.)
>
>  BAINES [OC]: We wanted to live forever, so the Doctor made sure that we did.

Does this scene happen in the original book? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not at all. There is no such scene in the novel.
The villains in the novel were six members of the Aubertides, a race of shapeshifters, who can transform into the shape of any creature they consume.
According to this [synopsis](http://www.drwhoguide.com/who_na38.htm) they

> all just got killed.

Here are the specific ends for the different characters:

- August

> Transformed mentally into John Smith after mistakenly absorbing human instead of Time Lord biodata. He tries to free a captured Joan and is then shot and killed by Hoff.

- Greeneye

> After getting captured in the end he tricks his guards and tries to escape by transforming into a cow. However, he is then taken to a slaughterhouse where he presumably dies.

- Laylock

> Unknown

- Serif

> Killed using explosives.

- [Aphasia](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Aphasia) (the equivalent to Daughter of Mine)

> Shot and killed during their attack on the school.

- Hoff

> Killed by the Doctor setting his equipment to self-destruct.